# Packaging a BlackBerry App for Release

Tags: blackberry, release, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I'm currently using the BB Plugin for Eclipse and am trying to generate a package without any .debug files and only one .cod and one .jad file to send to a client.

I'm a bit stuck on how to do this, I can't find a 'release build' setting and am having trouble finding any documentation on how to accomplish this or if I'm even on the right track.

Comment: check this link http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/Testing_and_Deployment_of_Applications@tkb/117/1/How_to_Deploy_and_Distribute_Applications_V1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click over your project, select "BlackBerry -> Package Project(s)"
2. In case it doesn't sign automatically, right click again, "BlackBerry -> Sign with signature tool"
3. Look for the generated "deliverables" folder in your project package explorer, then select the files for OTA deployment (inside "Web" folder). There you'll find one or more sibling cods and the correct jad descriptor.
4. profit

Comment: Ok, I'm looking in the web folder, I had to take over because of a separate issue and I'm new to BB development. 

The client is used to receiving one .cod and one .jad file and installing via download from a website. 

I'm looking in the web folder and i still see a bunch of sibling .cod files. I guess there's no way around that to consolidate them into one .cod file?

In my ignorance I sent them a .cod and .jad from the Standards folder and they got a "907 Invalid COD, Unable to import ZIP file error"

Thank you very much for your help. I've been getting a bit frustrated the last day or so.

Comment: you got "907 Invalid COD error because your .jad file is invalid means you you open your .jad file then you are able to see that mentioned .COD files are not present in your folder.

Comment: @user1368448 Unless you are using a legacy eclipse plugin version, the web folder should be there, with no debug files nor other crap. In this case, just copy as many cods as you see there along with the jad file. Otherwise, you are probably using a legacy plugin, in this case you also have many sibling cods, but these are packaged into a parent cod that IS NOT SUITABLE FOR OTA DEPLOYMENT. You need to unzip it and send the client the resulting cods and the jad.

Answer (score 0):

For OTA installation:

```
1. unzip your COD file.
2. now you got number of cod files like xyz.COD, xyz-1.COD, xyz-2.COD ... etc.
3. open your .jad file and verify listed .COD fils are mentioned in .jad file or not
4. upload all .COD files and .jad file in same location on web
5. open the .jad location on mobile device
```

Note: If your .jad file having incorrect .COD listed or still getting error then first delete your .jad file and .COD file and clean your project and then rebuild your project then follow above steps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all sign the application, after signing it upload the project on to your server and after uploading it take the .jad file and make a link of the path of the project where it is uploaded and then give that to the client and then he can download the application from there and can install it.

Answer (score 0):

When we sign `Blackberry Application` successfully we can able to install that app in device and also able to upload to `our Server` or `Blackberry App world`.  we have just need `.cod & .jar` file to upload in BB app world as well as in device . you r going on the right way .. Go ahead .